# How to do a rounded trapeze inside another trapeze with css

Tags: css, svg, rounded-corners

I need help with this problem

I want to do with css a figure like this:

[image: trapeze with protuberance]

I want to do a trapeze with a "rounded" protuberance in the middle.

I tried to put a trapeze back with z-index 0 an the other rounded with z-index 1, but i couldn't. Another solution for me was using svg but neither, it complicated me more.

Thanks for your help.

I tried to do this:

```
<style>
.left {
height: 66px;
background: blue;
float: left;
position: relative;
border-top-right-radius: 19px;
width: 370px;
}

.left:after {
content: '';
position: absolute;
right: -23.5px;
bottom: 0px;
border-top: rgba(255,255,255,0.1) 56px solid;
border-left: 26px solid #0000ff;
width: 0;
z-index: 1;
}

#trapezoid {

border-bottom: 100px solid #0000ff;
border-right: 50px solid transparent;
height: 0;
width: 330px;

 }
```

`

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow, please show us what you've tried so far, we can't do much without seeing your style and markup.

Comment: Do you mean a trapezoid?

Comment: you have a set of those questions? :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52980984/put-two-rounded-trapezes-with-css

Answer (score 1):

You can use skew transformation like follow:

```css
.box {
  height:100px;
  margin-right:50px;
  position:relative;
  z-index:0;
  transform:skew(25deg);
  transform-origin:bottom left;
}
.box:before {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  right:20px;
  bottom:50%;
  background:green;
}

.box:after {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  top:50%;
  left:0;right:0;bottom:0;
  background:green;
  border-top-right-radius:20px;
}

body {
 margin:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Reduce the width of trapezoid

```css
.left {
height: 66px;
background: blue;
float: left;
position: relative;
border-top-right-radius: 19px;
width: 370px;
}

.left:after {
content: '';
position: absolute;
right: -23.5px;
bottom: 0px;
border-top: rgba(255,255,255,0.1) 56px solid;
border-left: 26px solid #0000ff;
width: 0;
z-index: 1;
}

#trapezoid {

border-bottom: 80px solid #0000ff;
border-right: 50px solid transparent;
height: 0;
width: 300px;

 }
```

```html
<div id="trapezoid"></div>
<div class="left"></div>
```